# How i can create a pattern for a given String of data in JAVA?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

SID:SP19-BCS-123,FName:Aksam,LName:Basheer,CNIC:54321-1234567-1,Age:22,CGPA:3.45,EmailAddress:SP19-BCS-123@cuilahore.edu.pk

Comment: Welcome to SO! What information are you trying to match or extract here? Have you made an attempt at solving it yourself? Please see [ask].

Comment: The information that i am trying to match is provided in the body and i have tried it myself and i am facing a lot of trouble in order to develop it.

Comment: Please post your attempt. I see an input string but what _part(s)_ of the string are you interested in extracting? Please show your exact output.

Comment: i am interested in the whole part of the given string to match.

Comment: That's trivial. Matching the entire string means you're done--you already have the string so you don't need to write any code. If you mean validate whether a string matches this format, again, there's no specification, no attempt--nothing. You'll need to provide details and code as an edit to the post if you want an answer.

Comment: No i am asking if Some user enter enters a wrong value for CNIC like the user CNIC number is ending with 2 digits but it should end with a single digit accorifing to the given input. How i can achieve that ?

Comment: You want them to match this exactly, i.e. `s.equals(input)`? I see no specification given here. If you have logic that this needs to match, please state it as an edit to your post, e.g. "three digits followed by SP19..." etc etc. Otherwise, it's impossible to know what parts of this are variable and what aren't. And an attempt needs to be given.

Answer (score 0):

You can split it by commas and that would give you key-value pairs:

```
String[] result = s.split(",");
```

And after that you could access the keys and values like this:

```
for (String keyValues: result) {
   String[] keyValuesSplit = keyValues.split(":");
   String key = keyValuesSplit[0];
   String value = keyValuesSplit[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks For Your Response. I don't want to split them i want to create a pattern of the given String so i can match it with any given string.

Answer (score 0):

**Here some other alternatives:**

**Alternative 1 - split:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "SID:SP19-BCS-123,FName:Aksam,LName:Basheer,CNIC:54321-1234567-1"
            + ",Age:22,CGPA:3.45,EmailAddress:SP19-BCS-123@cuilahore.edu.pk";

    Map<String, String> resultMap = Arrays.stream(input.split(","))
            .map(s -> s.split(":"))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(array -> array[0], array -> array[1]));

    //Generate output
    resultMap.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
            .forEach(entry -> 
                    System.out.printf("Key: '%s' -> Value: '%s'%n"
                            , entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
}
```

**Output Alternative 1:**

```
Key: 'Age' -> Value: '22'
Key: 'CGPA' -> Value: '3.45'
Key: 'CNIC' -> Value: '54321-1234567-1'
Key: 'EmailAddress' -> Value: 'SP19-BCS-123@cuilahore.edu.pk'
Key: 'FName' -> Value: 'Aksam'
Key: 'LName' -> Value: 'Basheer'
Key: 'SID' -> Value: 'SP19-BCS-123'
```

**Alternative 2 - regex:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "SID:SP19-BCS-123,FName:Aksam,LName:Basheer,CNIC:54321-1234567-1"
            + ",Age:22,CGPA:3.45,EmailAddress:SP19-BCS-123@cuilahore.edu.pk";

    String inputTrailingComma = String.format("%s,", input);

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("([^:]+):([^,]+),").matcher(inputTrailingComma);

    while(matcher.find()) {
        String key = matcher.group(1);
        String value = matcher.group(2);
        
        //Generate output
        System.out.printf("Key: '%s' -> Value: '%s'%n", key, value);
    }
}
```

**Output Alternative 2:**

```
Key: 'SID' -> Value: 'SP19-BCS-123'
Key: 'FName' -> Value: 'Aksam'
Key: 'LName' -> Value: 'Basheer'
Key: 'CNIC' -> Value: '54321-1234567-1'
Key: 'Age' -> Value: '22'
Key: 'CGPA' -> Value: '3.45'
Key: 'EmailAddress' -> Value: 'SP19-BCS-123@cuilahore.edu.pk'
```